# C++ Divide and conquer square matrix multiplication problems

Tags: c++, matrix, divide-and-conquer, multiplication

I'm trying to do divide and conquer matrix multiplication so i can parallelize it, but I'm getting half random garbage numbers and half 0's in the result, e.g.  on a 2x2 matrix "[[15909360,0][15909360,0]]". This is what I have so far based on [the algorithm on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm#Shared-memory_parallelism)  but I don't really know where to go from here. I'm not using pointers yet for the partitioning or threads. This is homework btw.

```
void partition(const std::vector<std::vector<IntElement> >& m, std::vector<std::vector<IntElement> >& m11, std::vector<std::vector<IntElement> >& m12,
                 std::vector<std::vector<IntElement> >& m21, std::vector<std::vector<IntElement> >& m22, int n){
for(int i=0;i<n/2;i++)
 for(int j=0;j<n/2;j++){
  m11[i][j] = m[i][j]; // top left
  m12[i][j] = m[i][j + n / 2]; // top right
  m21[i][j] = m[i + n / 2][j]; // bottom left
  m22[i][j] = m[i + n / 2][j + n / 2]; // bottom right
 }
};
void add(std::vector<std::vector<IntElement> >& C, std::vector<std::vector<IntElement> >& T, int n){
if(n==1){
  C[0][0] += C[0][0] + T[0][0];
}
else{
std::vector<std::vector<IntElement> > c11(n/2, std::vector<IntElement>(n/2)), c12(n/2, std::vector<IntElement>(n/2)),
  c21(n/2, std::vector<IntElement>(n/2)), c22(n/2, std::vector<IntElement>(n/2));
std::vector<std::vector<IntElement> > t11(n/2, std::vector<IntElement>(n/2)), t12(n/2, std::vector<IntElement>(n/2)),
  t21(n/2, std::vector<IntElement>(n/2)), t22(n/2, std::vector<IntElement>(n/2));
partition(C, c11, c12, c21, c22, n);
partition(T, t11, t12, t21, t22, n);

add(c11, t11, n/2);
add(c12, t12, n/2);
add(c21, t21, n/2);
add(c22, t22, n/2);
 } 
};
void multiply(std::vector<std::vector<IntElement> >& C, const std::vector<std::vector<IntElement> >& A,
          const std::vector<std::vector<IntElement> >& B, int n){
if(n==1)
    C[0][0] += A[0][0] * B[0][0];
else{
  std::vector<std::vector<IntElement> > T(n, std::vector<IntElement>(n));
  std::vector<std::vector<IntElement> > a11(n/2, std::vector<IntElement>(n/2)), a12(n/2, std::vector<IntElement>(n/2)),
    a21(n/2, std::vector<IntElement>(n/2)), a22(n/2, std::vector<IntElement>(n/2));
  std::vector<std::vector<IntElement> > b11(n/2, std::vector<IntElement>(n/2)), b12(n/2, std::vector<IntElement>(n/2)),
    b21(n/2, std::vector<IntElement>(n/2)), b22(n/2, std::vector<IntElement>(n/2));
  std::vector<std::vector<IntElement> > c11(n/2, std::vector<IntElement>(n/2)), c12(n/2, std::vector<IntElement>(n/2)),
    c21(n/2, std::vector<IntElement>(n/2)), c22(n/2, std::vector<IntElement>(n/2));
  std::vector<std::vector<IntElement> > t11(n/2, std::vector<IntElement>(n/2)), t12(n/2, std::vector<IntElement>(n/2)),
    t21(n/2, std::vector<IntElement>(n/2)), t22(n/2, std::vector<IntElement>(n/2));

  partition(A, a11, a12, a21, a22, n);
  partition(B, b11, b12, b21, b22, n);
  partition(C, c11, c12, c21, c22, n);
  partition(T, t11, t12, t21, t22, n);

  multiply(c11, a11, b11, n/2);
  multiply(c12, a11, b12, n/2);
  multiply(c21, a21, b11, n/2);
  multiply(c22, a21, b12, n/2);

  multiply(t11, a12, b21, n/2);
  multiply(t12, a12, b22, n/2);
  multiply(t21, a22, b21, n/2);
  multiply(t22, a22, b22, n/2);

  add(C, T, n);
}
return;
};
SquareMatrix& SquareMatrix::operator*=(const SquareMatrix& m){
  std::vector<std::vector<IntElement> > C(n, std::vector<IntElement>(n));
  multiply(C, elements, m.elements, n);
  elements = C;
  return *this;
}

SquareMatrix operator*(const SquareMatrix& a, const SquareMatrix& b){
  SquareMatrix c = a;
  c *= b;
  return c;
}
```

EDIT: I changed C[0][0] += C[0][0] + T[0][0]; in add() to  C[0][0] += T[0][0]; Also I made a unpartition function that basically does the reverse and puts the partitions back into C and T after multiplying and adding:

```
void unpartition(std::vector<std::vector<IntElement> >& m,std::vector<std::vector<IntElement> >& m11, std::vector<std::vector<IntElement> >& m12,
           std::vector<std::vector<IntElement> >& m21, std::vector<std::vector<IntElement> >& m22, int n){
for(int i=0;i<n/2;i++)
for(int j=0;j<n/2;j++){
  m[i][j] = m11[i][j]; // top left
  m[i][j + n / 2] = m12[i][j]; // top right
  m[i + n / 2][j] = m21[i][j]; // bottom left
  m[i + n / 2][j + n / 2] = m22[i][j]; // bottom right
 }
}
```

My vectors get initialized correctly after I fixed the default constructor for my IntElement class.

Comment: Did you try debugging your code? Perhaps do the steps by hand on paper and compare with the program?

Comment: FYI: you can make your code much more readable (to us, and to yourself) by aliasing your vector type with something like `using elem_mat_t = std::vector<std::vector<IntElement> >;` at the top of your file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at our page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); what is the smallest, simplest multiplication example that produces the error?

Comment: But just at first glance it looks like you never initialize those local vector<vector>s `T,a11,b11,c11,d11`. They are NOT zero-initialized.

Comment: I would suggest you to not use vectors of vectors as matrices because they result in very inefficient data organization. The best way probably is to write a wrapper class that stores the data in a 1D vector.

Answer (score 0):

Your `partition` function makes copies of the data in the source vectors.  In `multiply` and `add`, you final series of calls (`multiply(c11, a11, b11, n/2)`, `add(c11, t11, n/2)`) will modify those submatrix objects.  This does not modify the original `C`, or `T` matrices.  `T` will stay filled with zeroes, and `C` will get occasional updates from 1x1 matrices.  You need to "unpartition" the results back into the appropriate matrices.

And the single element case in `add` is wrong.  `C[0][0] += C[0][0] + T[0][0];` should either be `C[0][0] += T[0][0];` or `C[0][0] = C[0][0] + T[0][0];` (but not both).

Answer (score -1):

The inner vectors in variables `T,a11,b11,c11,d11` are never initialized. They contain the garbage which is used in those 4 parititons calls.

EDIT: The above statement is false, as Alan Birtles pointed out they are initialized by default constructor of `IntElement`. I still believe that it might be just a typedef for `int` in which case my argument stands.

Comment: Vector elements will be initialised by the default constructor of `IntElement` whatever type that is, presumably that does something sensible like initialise to zero

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes, you are right, my mistake. If `IntElement` is a just typedef for `int` then it won't. I believe that might be the case so I will leave the answer here, but feel free to downvote as it's not correct.

Comment: i tried initializing and i got a matrix with all zeroes so if it is needed there's still something else too. IntElement is a class that holds an int.

Comment: it indeed isn't needed just make sure your classes default constructor assigns a default value

Comment: Even a vector of ints will be initialised to 0, all elements of a vector will always be initialised